# 2011 27 inch iMac disable internal drive

Tags: external-disk

I'd like to know if there is a way to completely disable the internal disk as I am now booting from an external SSD.  It seems like fsck_msdos is constantly running on the old internal drive which prevents disk utility from loading properly as it always shows "Loading Disks"  I've tried erasing through diskutil in terminal but get an error that it can't be unmounted I believe the error is -69888.  Also, if i try manually running repairDisk or verifyDisk it just hangs and the checking prerequisites step.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you, from terminal (Applications/Utility) give the result of command `diskutil list`?

Comment: For the internal drive terminal was giving all 3 partitions GUID,EFI, and the main partition.  I actually ended up biting the bullet and opening it up and taking the old disk out.  I’m still curious as to what typically causes this error for future reference but I can’t do any testing at this point.  Thanks for your help.